# Firebase return null for one user but fine for others

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this simple userPowerData collection:

I am fetching this data like this:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("userBatteryData/Tony Morgan")

ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(100).on('value', function(snapshot) {

    console.log(snapshot)
});
```

The above code prints null when I provide this user:Tony Morgan

[image]

Documents of successfully fetched record:

[image]

I don't know whats wrong with this one document of user: Tony Morgan

Comment: Most likely you have whitespace or some other unprintable character around the `Tony Morgan` key in the database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I already made sure of that, there is no whitespace or hidden character around that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen since we are fetching lots of records against each user, could this be the reason that firebase is blocking is after reaching certain limits?

Comment: That would typically show up as an error message. Is there any chance you can put a minimal repro up in a site like jsbin or stackblitz?